# How to make a 301 redirect from https to http for the whole site (nginx/1.4.6 server)

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I am very very sorry if i asked a stupid question))
I am an SEO analyst and i have to give my boss a code which will be used to redirect visitors from https to http version of the website.

Please give me the example of the code/scipt

Thanks,
Stan

Comment: Normally it is the other way around http->https

Comment: no no... we don't plan to use the SSL certificate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a question for serverfault.

They have [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) answer for the other way around.

for you something like:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       [....]
}

server {
       listen         443;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       rewrite        ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;

       ssl            on;
}
```

Comment: This will make the server redirect visitors from https version to http version? are you sure?))

P.S.  what should be instead of this? ====>  [....]