# Is there away to redirect people who erroneously type in https into a browser for a site with no SSL?

Tags: http, https

I had acquired a little, old, static website about 4 years ago. It does not have, nor has it ever had, an SSL.

The business owner has contacted me a few times in the past year citing the website is giving users (her and her customers) a security warning. I finally got her to send me a screen shot and they are using HTTPS in the browser to access the website.

I will probably never know WHY (I asked).

Is there a way to redirect people who are attempting to access a website by typing in https when there is no ssl and it should just be http?

It is the only thing I can think of doing.

I found this on StackOverflow [How to make a 301 redirect from https to http for the whole site (nginx/1.4.6 server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842595/how-to-make-a-301-redirect-from-https-to-http-for-the-whole-site-nginx-1-4-6-se)

And I was already directed to, ServerFault by Nelson Teixiera and when I posted there I was told:

"Unfortunately, many SO people, apparently including Nelson Teixeira, have no clue what's topical here, but feel inclined to sent people over here anyway. He was wrong. How about fixing your SSL so the warnings go away? It's 2015 after all... –  Sven"

Comment: Who exactly is "the business owner"? What "business"? What's your relationship with them? I'm asking because people seldom type an address (with https:) into their browser bars: if lots of people are doing it, I'm guessing they're following a link, and some idiot has added the 's' to the link. If you can find that and get whoever-it-is to fix it, the problem will go away.

Comment: Mike K - I think you are spot on.  They are a local florist shop. I just manage their yrly hosting/domain. They admit to being computer illiterate.  I found they also have a website through another outfit (think like FTD) where people can buy flowers online, that is using a .net version of their domain.  MAYBE to access that they use https and now they think they have to access the .com via httpS? Perhaps maybe someone told them the 'S' provides security?  I called there and asked them to pull up the website. Then I told them to STOP typing in httpS & delete any bookmarks.  Who knows. SMH

Comment: More likely they have a listing on a directory somewhere (maybe with this other outfit) where someone has added an 's' to their link. The fact that it's happening to customers implies that it's not a bookmark or typing issue.

Comment: I suggested something like that to them as well. Who knows, maybe they printed it wrong on some business cards or something.  They couldn't find my business (as in my contact info) in the yellow pages, and didn't notice it's in the signature block of all of my emails, on my invoices, and on my website. So they wrote me a letter about this and sent it with their payment.   So who knows.   *Shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

Not without an SSL site.

You can redirect a user as long as you have a valid HTTPS site with correct certificate running on the server. No valid HTTPS site means no communication with the browser and therefore no chance to send any information (e.g. a redirection) to the user's browser.

Anyway in such a situation IMHO it does not make sense to redirect the users back to the non-secure website as the HTTPS connection can be directly used to display the web-page.

Comment: There is no https site.  And there is no certificate.

Comment: They are manually using https:// DomainNameHere to get to the website. The website has no SSL (never has).  They get their browser warning screen, panic and call the business, who has now called me.  

I don't know why they are typing in HTTPS - and why they have so many customers (enough to complain) doing so.  

When I called the business and told them to simply stop typing in https they sounded so dazed and confused.  :-\

Comment: Customers can only get a warning screen if your site is on a server that serves multiple sites including HTTPS enabled sites. If your site would run on a server that only serves HTTP-only sites the customers would only get an time-out in the browser and an error message "site is not available" or something similar). Anyway if the customers expect you to have an HTTPS enabled site you should set-up one. No customers means no business...

Comment: Robert - they do not EXPECT to have an SSL site.  The website owners don't hardly know how to use a computer let alone what an SSL is for.  And the website is only a simple static html page, no ecommerce or anything.  Why would anyone expect a site like that to have an SSL / use HTTPS?   :-\